# MySQL triggers check if insert is successfull or not

Tags: mysql

As mentioned in the title, i have created a trigger that catches when a new value is inserted in the 'candidate' table, and stores some information in the table 'history'. However, i would also like to store if the insertion is successful or not, but cannt quite seem to get it to work. I have tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cand_i BEFORE INSERT ON candidate FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE action varchar(10);
IF(EXISTS(select username from candidate where username=NEW.username)) THEN
    SET action='Failed';
ELSE SET action='Success';
END IF;
INSERT INTO history (actiontype,actiondate,actionsuccess,actiontable,username)
VALUES ('Insert',now(),action,'Candidate',NEW.username);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to make it an `AFTER` trigger if you want to check if the data was inserted, but if you do, then the fact that the trigger was called means the insert succeeded, so no need to check whether the data is in the table or not.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your reply. I have actually tried that, but lets say when i try to insert the same value twice in the table, error pops up " Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'Primary'  , and the 'history' table does not get updated. I want to store the insert action , whether it is successful or not

Answer (score 1):

**If** you are using a non-transactional table (e.g. MyISAM) for the `history` table, you can achieve the result you want by using `BEFORE` and `AFTER` triggers as described under **Original Answer**. If both `candidate` and `history` are transactional tables (e.g. InnoDB), if the `INSERT` fails, the entire transaction - **including** the operation performed in the `BEFORE` trigger - gets rolled back, so this method will not work. In that case you need to use the `AFTER` trigger described below, and perform the `INSERT` to the `history` table prior to the `INSERT` to the candidate table e.g.

```
INSERT INTO history (actiontype,actiondate,actionsuccess,actiontable,username)
    VALUES ('Insert',now(),'Failed','Candidate','<username>');
INSERT INTO candidate (..., username, ...)
    VALUES (..., '<username>', ...);
```

**Original Answer**

Since you want to record the `INSERT`, regardless of whether it succeeded or not, you will need to implement this using two triggers. In the `BEFORE` trigger, simply create an entry with a failed status, and in the `AFTER` trigger, update the status to `Success`. Since `AFTER` triggers are only run if the row operation succeeds ([manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)), this will do what you want.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cand_i BEFORE INSERT ON candidate FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO history (actiontype,actiondate,actionsuccess,actiontable,username)
VALUES ('Insert',now(),'Failed','Candidate',NEW.username);
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER cand_i_a AFTER INSERT ON candidate FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE history
SET actionsuccess = 'Success'
WHERE actiontype = 'Insert' AND actiontable = 'Candidate' AND username = NEW.username;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i saw your reply earlier and tried a similar thing.I also tried the code you suggested as well. 'History' is indeed updated if the value was succesfully inserted , but if it was not, nothing happens, here is a screenshot of the console output: http://prntscr.com/ly34ez  . The username is set as primary key, and i think thats why it prints the error message, but shouldn't the 'BEFORE' trigger still work?

Comment: @apr0vleptos I'm pretty sure the problem is that your tables are transactional tables. I've tested the code with InnoDB and MyISAM tables and it works fine for MyISAM tables but not at all for InnoDB. I've updated my answer with a workaround for transactional tables.

Comment: @Nick It might be worth mentioning (or, if you meant that, emphasizing) that you can make *just* the history table myisam (it is common practice for this kind of problem). Then the original query on innodb can be in transactions (or fail), but the log is still persistent.

Comment: @Solarflare re-reading, you're right, that isn't clear. I've edited to hopefully make it more so. thanks.